# Changing Git Submodule Commit

Tags: git, ubuntu

Upon attempting to 'build' from a repository using Apache Ant i get an error similar to this

```
Fetched in submodule path 'externals/ringojs-fork', but it did not contain 
298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf. Direct fetching of that commit 
failed.
```

From what I have read I think I need to change the commit at which one of my submodules is pulling.

As seen in the picture my ringojs-fork external submodule is pulling from a commit starting 298e. How do i change this to be the master?

I am on Linux Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "pulling at/from a commit"? On principle, each branch can have an upstream set to a specific remote *branch*, but not to a specific *commit*. Also, you seem to use a UI. If you tell which it might help some people help you.

Comment: The submodule, from what i can tell, is downloading not from the master brand but from a different one. i would like for it to be downloading from the master.

Comment: Are you interacting with git through your UI, or command line ?

Comment: Through the command line.

Comment: So `git branch -u <upstream>/<nameofTheRemote> <nameOfYourLocal>` should be fine. Example if for ringojs if your remote target branch is named notMaster : `git branch -u upstream/notMaster ringojs`. Here `<upstream>` is a placeholder for the name of your remote (usually `origin` but it's only a convention)

Comment: I was not too sure at start, but it could be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch/2286030).

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious. What should I replace notMaster with? It's the ringojs-fork submodule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... From what I have read I think I need to change the commit at which one of my submodules is pulling.

Maybe.  It may also be the case that you just need to poke someone to update the upstream submodule.  Or, maybe you should just use a different commit in the superproject.  Or maybe your submodule is cloned as a *shallow* repository, but should not be.  (I think this last is the most likely, based on the fact that https://github.com/ringo/ringojs/tree/298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf exists.)

If the problem is in fact a shallow clone, navigating to the submodule repository and running `git fetch --unshallow` should fix it.  You could use `git submodule foreach git fetch --unshallow` to do that.

#### Background

You probably already know what a Git repository is: it's a collection (or database) of *commits*, with each commit representing a complete, intact snapshot of an entire source tree.  Some particular commits are especially important, either right now, or always, so these commits have *names:* a branch name, like `master`, names the *latest* commit on that branch.  It's important because it's *new!* or *shiny!* or whatever.  Meanwhile, a tag name, like `v1.2`, names a commit some *person* thought was important, such as a stable release.

Each of these names—branch or tag, or really, any other human-readable name you can use in a Git repository like `origin/master` or whatever—is actually just a name for a raw hash ID.  These hash IDs, which include things like `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf`, are apparently-random, big ugly hexadecimal numbers that are useless to humans.  You have just seen an example of how such a number is not useful to you.  But they are what *Git* uses to check out specific commits.  When you use a name like `master` or `v1.2`, Git translates that name into the correct hash ID, and checks out that commit.

Because a Git repository is, at least **normally**—this becomes important soon, *fully self contained*, Git can make sure that all the names are valid and identify valid commits.  When you tell Git: *check out `master`*, it's never the case that the name `master` exists and names commit `a123456...` and yet that *commit* doesn't exist.  Either the commit *does* exist, and `master` can name it, or the commit *doesn't* exist, and master *cannot* name it.<sup>1</sup>

When you use a branch name to check out one specific commit—by running `git checkout master` or `git checkout develop`, for instance—Git turns the name into the hash ID, locates that commit in the database, and extracts that commit into a *work-tree* where you can use it and/or work on it.  The commits inside the database are in a form usable only by Git itself, so without a work-tree, you could not do any work.  At the same time that Git extracts the commit, Git *remembers* the *name* for you, so that you are now "on a branch".

You can, however, also select any historical commit you like, by its raw hash ID, and run `git checkout a123456...`.  That commit must *exist* of course, but assuming it does, Git extracts *that* commit into your work-tree, and remembers that you're not on *any* branch now.  Instead, Git says that you have a "detached HEAD".

In general, you *get* a Git repository by cloning:

```
git clone <url> <directory>
```

clones the repository found at the given URL, and puts it in a particular directory.  The last step of `git clone` is to `git checkout` a branch or tag—often the branch name `master`, but you can add arguments to `git clone` to say what to check out.

---

<sup>1</sup>This gives rise to the interesting case of a new, completely-empty Git repository.  In such a Git repository, there are no commits yet.  This means there are no branches!  The branch name `master` does not exist yet, in a new, completely-empty repository.  The very first commit you create *becomes* the latest commit *on* branch `master`, and in so doing, also creates the *name* `master`.  This is because the name must always contain a valid commit hash ID.

---

#### Submodules

With all that in mind, let's take a moment to describe what a *submodule* is.  The short version is that a submodule is just another Git repository.  The only thing special about the submodule is that it exists *because* some *other* Git repository—which Git calls the *superproject*—says: "while I am my own Git repository, I would like to use another Git repository too."  The superproject is required to supply the information you would have passed to `git clone`: the URL, and the path.

If you start working *in* the submodule, though, you find that it's almost always in the special "detached HEAD" state.  That's because instead of checking out a *branch* or a *tag*, the superproject *also* tells the submodule Git: *and by the way, after you've cloned or fetched everything, I want **one specific commit** and here is the hash ID: _______*.  The superproject supplies the raw hash ID—not a name like `master` or `v1.2`, just a raw hash ID.

**This is the source of the error you are seeing.**  The superproject repository you chose, some version of Ant, lists a submodule repository by name (apparently this ringojs-fork thing).  You can clone that other Git repository just fine.  But then, your superproject tells your Git system: *after getting the latest from ringojs-fork, check out commit `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf`.*  But commit `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf` **does not exist**.

Who's wrong?  Is it the superproject, when it says "use commit `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf`"?  Or is it the submodule, when it says "commit `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf` does not exist (yet)"?   Or maybe even both are wrong.  Well, sort of.  The submodule repository is a *repository*, so it should be self-contained and have everything.

#### Where things can go wrong

Git is a distributed version control system, meaning there are many copies of every repository.  Every clone is a copy, after all.  But some clones might be more up to date than others.  Suppose someone controlling this ringojs-fork forgot to run `git push` to update the GitHub clone.  Then that someone might have commit `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf`, but have never sent it out for everyone else.  In that particular case, you just need to get whoever controls this ringojs-fork to send that commit up, so that you can get it back down.

Or, perhaps `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf` existed at one time, and was available for everyone to use.  It might even be out there in some clones.  But something terrible was in `298e62daa64923b7bc1e4a085233529f907ba7bf`, so whoever controls the ringojs-fork had it carefully excised.  In other words, it *was* there, but isn't any more, and no one should ever ask for it.  (This situation is problematic since other people might depend on it, or have it and put it back, or at least try to put it back.  It's rarely good to rip commits out of public repositories like this.)  In this particular case, we see that your Ant repository—your superproject—depends on it.

Well, more precisely, **at least one specific commit** in your superproject depends on this commit in the submodule.  Maybe other commits in the superproject *don't*, in which case, if you switch to one of those other commits in the superproject, maybe that will cure the problem.  No commit can ever be changed, so the particular commit in the superproject that you are using right now will always ask for this other particular commit (by hash ID) in the submodule.  If the submodule's commit should never be asked-for, this particular commit in the superproject should simply never be *used*.

Or, there's one more possibility.  I mentioned above that a repository is normally completely self-contained.  There's a special exception, though, that's very common, called a *shallow clone*.  A shallow clone is a clone that deliberately omits a lot of commits, so as to make cloning faster.

Omitting lots of commits to make cloning faster is great, up until someone asks for one of those commits.  Now, Git is not totally stupid—it is only just mostly stupid —so a shallow clone that omits some commit, also omits any *name* for that commit.  But superprojects don't ask for commits by *name*, they ask directly by raw hash IDs.  This means that if you make shallow clones of submodules, it's really easy for the superproject to call for a commit that was not copied in the clone step.

**The root of the problem is that a superproject lists a submodule's commit by raw hash ID, and the two Git repositories are only loosely coupled.**  Anything that causes a commit in the superproject repository to list a hash ID that is not available, for whatever reason, in the submodule repository, will lead to this error.  That includes the occasional failure to push, but mostly includes cases of shallow cloning.

(Note that if a submodule *moves*, from one GitHub URL to another for instance, you may have to adjust the submodule clone, which may list the old URL, in the same way you have to adjust the superproject's URL if the superproject's URL changes.)